# how to make a skype call from webpage with dynamic phoe number

Tags: javascript, skype

i found the code from [skype dev site](http://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/skype-uri-tutorial-webpages)

for calls from my webpage:

```
Skype.ui({
    name: "call",
    element: "skypeButton",
    participants: ["+390852298965"],
    imageSize: 32
});
```

But i need to make calls using dynamics phome numbers, recovered from a textbox, for example:

```
Skype.ui({
    name: "call",
    element: "skypeButton",
    participants: function () {
        return [$("#phonenumber").val()];
    },
    imageSize: 32
});
```

but this code doesn't works...
hope someone can help me!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hey try it something like that

```
 var var={
        name: "call",
        element: "skypeButton",
        participants: ["+390852298965"],
        imageSize: 32
    };
    var.participants=[$("#phonenumber").val()];
    Skype.ui(var);
```